# cocoa -[Person copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm doing some cocoa programming follows the [Cocoa programming for Mac OS X](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/cocoa_programming_for_mac_os_x_th_edition_), I'm trapped in Chapter 8(`NSArrayController`), I'm following the guide defined in that book, but I don't know why the app always raising `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error.

My code is here [RaiseMan](https://www.dropbox.com/s/18ziop5d7dmtpan/RaiseMan.zip?dl=0), If you have  any suggestion, Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it myself. The behaviour of  `NSArrayController` `add` method is to copy an object, not holding the `pointer` of the object,  What I've encountered is I haven't implement `NSCoping` protocol in class `Person`, I fixed it like this:

in *Person.h* declar `NSCoping`:

```
@interface Person : NSObject <NSCopying> {
    NSString *personName;
    float expectedRaise;
}
```

and in *Person.m* implement it:

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return self;
}
```